como conecto mi formulario a mi base de datos por medio de express
me gustaria saber que problema tengo con mi codigo, al parecer lo que ingreso en mi formulario no se guarda en mi base de datos, los datos llegan a mi backend de express pero algo pasa, no se muy bien que podria, ya que en mi backend, cuando no uso la variable tituloNovel si no que ingreso los datos directamente se registran en mi backend, pero cuando lo hago con el formulario no sirve, use thunder client y me registra error 500, necesito ayuda en cuanto a por que no puedo conectar correctamente


///frontend

import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [formulario, setFormulario] = useState({
    tituloNovel: "",introducir el código aquí
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch("/novels", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formulario),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Success:", data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="h-auto w-auto bg-zinc-300/90 space-y-6 flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-6"
      >
        <h1 className="capitalize text-2xl underline">Crear una novela</h1>
        <label htmlFor="titulo">
          titulo
          <input
            name="tituloNovel"
            value={setFormulario.tituloNovel}
            id="titulo"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setFormulario({ ...formulario, name: e.target.value })
            }
            type="text"
            required
            className="w-full p-1 rounded outline outline-1 outline-zinc-300 shadow hover:outline-zinc-600/90"
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit" className="p-5">
          Enviar
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

////backend

const express = require("express");
const port = 3000;
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(morgan("combined"));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Parse incoming JSON data

const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

// Create a pool of connections
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "yosoymipropiodios",
  database: "novelas",
});

app.use(cors());

app.post("/novels", async (req, res) => {
  const { tituloNovel } = req.body;

  try {
    const connection = await pool.getConnection();
    const [results] = await connection.execute(
      "INSERT INTO `novelas` (`titulo`) VALUES(?)",
      [tituloNovel]
    );
    console.log(results);

    res.json({ message: "novela creada exitosamente" });

    // Release the connection back to the pool after successful execution
    connection.release();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ err: "Error al crear la novela" });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`el servidor esta escuchando en el puerto ${port}`);
});


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Estas mostrando dos errores distintos.. tu front le pega a un puerto que no existe (porque en la otra imagen le estas pegando al 3000).. y en esa imagen, tenes un error 500 que no mostras porque solo mostras el mensaje de error y no esta completo...

Estoy de acuerdo con @gbianchi en relación al puerto, puede que solo sea eso, pero si sigue entonces hasta donde llega tu alcance cuando tratas de comunicarte al backend? por ejemplo logras entrar aquí app.post("/novels", async (req, res) => {...resto del código console.log visibles etc?

Tu problema principal es que estas utilizando la ruta únicamente "/novels" y por defecto el servidor local va a ser el del frontend, en este caso http://localhost:5173/novels Para corregirlo en el fetch hay que llamar al servidor local, en tu caso http://localhost:3000/novels:
fetch("http://localhost:3000/novels", {

Tambien hay otros detalles a tener en cuenta, en el value del input hay que incluir el valor del formulario del estado de la siguiente manera:
<input
        name="tituloNovel"
        value={formulario.tituloNovel}

El manejo del hook setFormulario sirve para establecer un valor, no para llamar.
Otro punto a tener en cuenta, es la manipulación del formulario por medio de onChange. name identifica al input y value el valor.
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const {  name, value } = e.target
    setFormulario({ ...formulario, [name]: value })
  }

Formuario:
<input
        name="tituloNovel"
        value={formulario.tituloNovel}
        id="titulo"
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        required
        className="w-full p-1 rounded outline outline-1 outline-zinc-300 shadow hover:outline-zinc-600/90"
      />

